# Why does data merging occur when inserting data with the same timestamp in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

The following is the inserted data

```sql
CREATE TABLE air (
     visibility DOUBLE,
     temperature DOUBLE,
     pressure DOUBLE,
     TAGS(station)
);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature) VALUES
(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, pressure) VALUES
(1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 77);
```

```
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| time                       | station    | visibility | temperature | pressure |
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| 2022-10-19T07:40:00.290401 | XiaoMaiDao | 56.0       | 69.0        |          |
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+

+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| time                       | station    | visibility | temperature | pressure |
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| 2022-10-19T07:40:00.290401 | XiaoMaiDao | 56.0       | 69.0        | 77.0     |
+----------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

Why does data merging occur when inserting data with the same timestamp in CnosDB?